# Time Limit Exceeded in Leetcod

Tags: java

How can I optimise this code to be faster? I'm practicing in the LeetCode and I think it's correct but I don't know for sure since it only passed 105 out of 160 test cases.

Should I keep this code and optimise it or I need to change my thinking about solving this problem?

```
class Solution {
    public int threeSumClosest(int[] nums, int target) {        
    //    int sum = 100;
        int fin=0;
        int com=0;
        int w = nums[0]+nums[1]+nums[2];  
        int n = Math.abs(target - w);
        
        if (nums.length == 3) {
            return nums[0]+nums[1]+nums[2];  
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                for (int k = j+1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                    int z = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k];                     
                    int p = Math.abs(target - z);
                    if (p < n || p == n) {
                        n = p;
                        fin = z;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need three nested loops?

Comment: Change your approach, sort the array and add pruning to optimize time cost.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a complexity of O(n^3).

From your code and method name I assume the problem is about finding a triplet from a given array that sums closest to a given target. Your approach is greedy and usage of 3 nested loops here resulted into a costly time complexity. You can change your approach here to resolve this issue.

What you can do is sort the array in ascending order and then use two-pointer approach to find the closest sum. This will reduce the time complexity to O(n^2).

See the approach in detail [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/find-three-elements-sum-array).